# AngularJS validation not working in foreach loop

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, dynamic

I have a foreach loop that pulls in the view and generates a list dynamically. I am trying to put validation in the input fields in angular js but it is not firing.

code:

```
 @{
    foreach( item i in Products)
     { 
     <tr id = "@(@item.name)">
      <td >
          <input  ng-pattern="^[0-2][1-4]$" id="@(@item.amount)" ng-model="@(@item.amount)" /> 
      </td>
     </tr>
     }
  }
```

Comment: @{
    foreach( item i in Products)
     { 
     <tr id = "@(@item.name)">
      <td >
          <input  ng-pattern="^[0-2][1-4]$" id="@(@item.amount)" ng-                 model="@(@item.amount)" /> 
      </td>
     </tr>
     }

  }

Comment: is this all wrapped in a form for validation? maybe show more more code around this and specify what exactly about the validation is "not working"

Comment: It seems razor syntax.